# Why this code is not giving me the elements with that classname?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I have the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read())

for x in soup.find_all(class_='logo'):
    

    try:
        if x.name == 'img':
            return url + '/' + x['src']
        elif x.name == 'a':
            children = x.findChildren("img", recursive=False)
            for c in children:
                
                return url + '/' + c['src']


    except:
        pass
```

The thing is that for the url https://www.sulamericaauto.com.br, is not giving me the img element on the page with that classname. Why is that? I am using
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1 and bs4==0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

It is because logo is not part of the html code from original response. It is loaded at later time by javascript jquery ajax call. It has nothing to do with python code.

Within original response there is code that fetches the menu html code where logo is contained.

```
<!-- Carregamento client side do menu -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var layoutresponsivo = "/includes/responsivo/menu-principal-responsivo.htm"
    $.get(layoutresponsivo, function (data)
    {
        $("#dummyMenuInstitucional").empty().append(jQuery(data).find('#menuInstitucional')); //TODO BARRA AZUL
        $("#dummyMenu").empty().append(jQuery(data).find('#menu'));
        $("#dummyBusca").empty().append(jQuery(data).find('#busca'));

        //Hide menu loader
        $(".sasTopo .loader").fadeOut();
    });
</script>
```

So if you need logo element try to fetch this url instead https://portal.sulamericaauto.com.br/includes/responsivo/menu-principal-responsivo.htm

Comment: great!  Thanks a lot!